# Jmeter Load Testing Calculations

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I need to run a Load test for 250 users for 1 hour. What are variable which I need to consider when I'm planning the load test?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration would be something like:

[image]

You might also want to specify Ramp-Up period, with the above setup JMeter will kick off all users in 1 second and normally people want to increase the load **gradually** in order to be able to correlate the increasing load with changing [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc.

More information:

- [JMeter - Elements of Test Plan - Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)
- [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide)